# html submit button not handling action .php

Tags: php, html, button, action

I'm trying to call a php file in a html form, as shown in my code, but the send button is not functioning, any ideas ?

```
<form id="contact-form" method="post" action="form_send.php">
                <fieldset>
                  <label class="name">
                    <input type="text" value="Your Name" onFocus="if(this.value=='Your Name'){this.value=''}" onBlur="if(this.value==''){this.value='Your Name'}">
                  </label>
                  <label class="phone">
                    <input type="text" value="Telephone" onFocus="if(this.value=='Telephone'){this.value=''}" onBlur="if(this.value==''){this.value='Telephone'}">
                  </label>
                  <label class="email">
                    <input type="email" value="Email" onFocus="if(this.value=='Email'){this.value=''}" onBlur="if(this.value==''){this.value='Email'}">
                  </label>
                  <label class="message">
                    <textarea onFocus="if(this.value=='Message'){this.value=''}" onBlur="if(this.value==''){this.value='Message'}">Message</textarea>
                  </label>
                  <div class="btns"> <a class="button" onclick="clearFunction()" >Clear</a> <a class="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Form" >Send</a> </div>
                </fieldset>
              </form>
```

Comment: Try `<button class="button" type="submit" name="submit">Send</button>` instead of an `href`.

Comment: `the send button is not functioning` So you expect us to imagine what happens?

Comment: You're welcome Hussein, *cheers*

Answer (score 2):

you are use `<a>` tag to submit the form

replace `<a class="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Form" >Send</a>` with `<input class="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Form" >`

Comment: thanks for your help, yes im using css for buttons style

Comment: you are using hyperlink tag <a> not an css

Answer (score 0):

You are not naming any inputs in your form..

```
<input **name='name'** value='Your name'>
<input **name='phone'** value='Phone'>
```

and so on..
for proccessing:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$name=$_POST['name'];
$phone=$_POST['phone'];
$xxx=$_POST['xxx'];
echo $name, $phone; //echoing data.
}
```

and so on.
**Don't forget to sanitize your data before submitting..(ANTI-SQL INJECTION)**

and instead of your *OnBlur* and *OnFocus* solution: `placeholder='Your name'`